# Reading a cursor output and saving into a data set in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble trying to figure this out. I am using SQL server stored procedures which open a cursor for a dynamic query and shoot out the result. for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
@results CURSOR VARYING OUTPUT
@id INT
AS
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(max)
SET @query = ' SELECT * from EMPtable where'+@id+'= emp.id'
SET @results = CURSOR FOR SELECT @query
OPEN @results
```

Then I close and de-allocate the cursor.
I have no idea how read the data set values and store them in a data table in C#. I tried using data adapter and data reader but everything returns a null value or returns an error.

Comment: this is not the procedure you want to use, to do what you want to do.  your entire procedure should just be `CREATE PROCEDURE EMP_GetByID @id INT AS BEGIN SELECT * FROM EMPtable WHERE id = @id END`

Comment: @JamieD77 that should be an answer. I nearly cried when I saw this procedure was using a cursor for a select statement.

Comment: @SeanLange none of it makes much sense. it wouldn't even compile if it wasn't putting the sql in a varchar because of `emp.id`

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can make your stored procedure simpler and easier to read by using the following. Notice how less confusing it is now:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spSelectEmployee
(
  @id int
)
AS BEGIN
  SELECT  *
  FROM    EMPtable
  WHERE   id = @id
END
```

Then, you can read it into a `DataTable` in c# like this and do something with it:

```cs
void GetEmployee(int employeeID)
{
    // 1
    // Open connection
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DataConnectionString))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        // 2
        // Create new DataAdapter
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("EXEC dbo.spSelectEmployee " + employeeID, sqlConnection))
        {
            // 3
            // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        // 4
        // Render data onto the screen
        // dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable; // <-- From your designer
        }
    }
}
```